# taking the largest number in the star fill class (scraping website)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm having trouble scraping the website:

https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/british-airways/page/1/.

I want to retrieve information on the number of stars fills, but on the website, if the star fill is 3 stars, then the star fill class is 1,2,3. how to take the biggest star fill and don't care about star class

[image]

Comment: You can just find list length of `<span class="star fill">`, this way you get number of stars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each review article, you can easily identify the maximum star rating given for the options (such as `Seat Comfort`, `Cabin Staff Service`, `Food & Beverages`, etc.)

If you notice the given star ratings are put inside the `<span class="star fill">` while the star rating not given are put inside the `<span class="star">`

This is how you can get the maximum/biggest star rating for a particular option in each review article:

- get to the specific option tag (for example, `td.review-rating-header.seat_comfort`)
- find all the `span` tags with `class="star fill"` (for example, `span.star.fill`) which will return a list and just take the item at the very last index (`[-1]`) to get the maximum star given.

This is how you can try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/british-airways/page/1/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
review_containers = soup.select('article[itemprop="review"]')

for review in review_containers:
    seat_comfort = review.select_one('td.review-rating-header.seat_comfort')
    seat_comfort_rating = seat_comfort.find_next_sibling('td').select('span.star.fill')[-1].text
    print(f"Seat Comfort rating: {seat_comfort_rating} Stars")
```

output:

```
Seat Comfort rating: 4 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 3 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 3 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 2 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 2 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 4 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 1 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 1 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 2 Stars
Seat Comfort rating: 2 Stars
```